# Put some line below of images ASP.Net MVC view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, image

I have made a page that populate images and write their name like this (ASP.Net MVC) :

[image]

Here is my code :

```
<span style=" display : block">
```

```
   <a href="<%= Url.Action("EditProduct", new { id = item.Id }) %>">
   <img src='<%= Url.Action( "getImg", "Product", new  { ShopId = item.Id }) %>'   alt="" /></a>

    <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)%>
<% }%>
</span>
```

But I want to put the Names below of the images. I tried some ways like table but I was unsuccessful. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<img src='<%= Url.Action( "getImg", "Product", new  { ShopId = item.Id }) %>' style="clear:both"  alt="" />
```

Comment: OK, I figured it out. You should wrap the Name of the Model in a div, like this:   <div><%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)%></div>

Answer (score 0):

Add `<br />` tag after over `</a>`

```
<span style=" display : block">
    <a href="<%= Url.Action("EditProduct", new { id = item.Id }) %>">
    <img src='<%= Url.Action( "getImg", "Product", new  { ShopId = item.Id }) %>'   alt="" /></a><br />
    <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)%> <%}%>
        </span>
```

Comment: Tnx. I tried this way but it does not work. It put the images below each other but I want to put images beside each other. I just want to put the Names below of them.